# Make hash on excel data to detect data changed with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with a lot of sheets (100+). Each sheet is independant. I would like to know if the data in a specific sheet has been altered since it last was opened. At the moment, I have a solution based on a for loop on all the relevant cells and calculate a checksum from there. If it is different, then the sheet has been changed. The problem is that I need to access a lot of cells and python is notoriously slow at that kind of task.

My question is: would you people have a better solution than my very naive one that would be more efficient?

I am using pyopenxl, but I could use another library for this specific task but it must be a python library.
The data is not of a single kind: there is a mix of numbers and strings in each sheet. But every sheet is formatted with the same pattern. (i.e. always the same data type at a given coordinate)

Comment: Try [pandas.util.hash_pandas_object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html?highlight=hash)

Comment: Your solution actually worked, this was what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Consider to post your solution as an answer.